# Create web app and mobile app with same MySQL DB on web server

Tags: php, json, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

- Hi all,
- **i want create mobile app (i use phonegap) that retrieve and insert data in MySQL Database on web server also i will create website that connected to the same Database using (PHP).**
- I need guidance:
- What topics should i know/use ?
- What things should be implemented in Web development process ?
- Can i use shared host or i will have to rent dedicated server ?
- Is phonegap the right choice to accomplish the project ?
  .........

Any guidance will be great.
Thank you All.

Comment: Not trying to be a Buzz Killington over here but shouldn't you be doing the work for your own grad project based on the information you were taught in school?  I mean phonegap builds out a basic backend for you for multiple platforms and has a ton of examples for use with a MySQL database.  If you're going to have someone tell you everything you need to do and what to use how are you going to ethically submit this project as your own?

Answer (score 0):

Your lack of familiarity with the technologies involved leads me to believe you are making a mole hill out of a mountain. All the skills involved need time/effort and no one answer here will cover your question.

There are various methods to achieve what you ask... I suggest starting with learning how to write some HTML5, then move on to doing a bit of Javascript and then follow it with a bit on jQuery. These skills are what you will use to place text on your web page or app.

After that, learn how to install MySQL, Apache, MySQL and PHP on your laptop. These skills will help you save data on to a server.

Then you need to learn how to combine them so that the data sent from your web app gets checked prior to saving on the server.

Then follow with how to read the data from the server and prepare it for re-display back on your web page or web app.

Once that is done - learn how to use the PhoneGap build service so you can package your app and try it on your device.

I suspect if you start now, and do 10-20 hours a week, you might get something buggy working by Christmas.

Best of luck!